# CSS3 border animation ghost

Tags: css, animation, border

I have this little border animation but has a ghost in the left top corner, a black dot, I don't know how to get rid of it... You can check it here: http://codepen.io/xaeoc/pen/xGRgze

```
    body {  
    background-color: #333;
    height: 230px;
    }

    .lluv {
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    border: solid red 1px;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 115px);
    }

    .ondas1 {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
    animation: ondas1 1s ease-out;
    }

    @keyframes ondas1 {
    0% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    top: calc(50% - 0px);
    left: calc(50% - 0px);
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
    }
    100% {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: calc(50% - 100px);
    left: calc(50% - 100px);
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `forwards` should be `animation: ondas1 1s ease-out forwards;`

demo - http://codepen.io/victorfdes/pen/EjNWNY

more explanation about [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

after the animation is complete it goes to default state which has `border 3px` thats the reason you are seeing the rounded element at the left top once you use `forwards` the animation doesnt go the the default stated instead it goes to the last state in the `keyframe`

Comment: Worked wonder full but, if you add a second element (ondas2) the dot comes back... [Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/xaeoc/pen/xGRgze ) How would you fix this one... I try a couple of things that didn't worked... So help again hahaha.

Comment: it is because you have added `.3s` delay for the second element so the border was visibel for `.3s` check this demo - http://codepen.io/victorfdes/pen/JdrdVP @Ka'deXaeoc

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the border in `ondas1`. This should remedy your issue.

[Sample](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpLgZL)

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 230px;
}

.lluv {
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  border: solid red 1px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: calc(50% - 115px);
}

.ondas1 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  left:-10px;  
  position: absolute;
  animation: ondas1 1s ease-out;
}

@keyframes ondas1 {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    top: calc(50% - 0px);
    left: calc(50% - 0px);
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  }
  100% {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: calc(50% - 100px);
    left: calc(50% - 100px);
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
}
```